# Switching wifi networks from an iphone

Tags: applications, wifi

I wonder if there's an App which helps me to easily switch to another wifi network without going through the "settings" screens of my iPhone. Nowadays more and more cars provide their own wifi network which you have to login to to give commands to the car. So an easy temporary switch to the car's network would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Without a jailbreak this is not possible because Apple doesn't allow this kind of feature on the App Store.